# How do I use Glide for multiple downloads?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I have this piece of code,        this is my first use of Glide, I still do not understand how to do it differently

```
                    try {
    Glide.with(this@TestBitmapActivity)
        .asBitmap()
        .load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mymodeapp-3f9a7.appspot.com/o/heroes%2Fman%2Fbg_hero.png?alt=media&token=2182a224-bb65-4f06-90d9-8e5c5d9b07d9")
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
            bg_imageview_test.setImageBitmap(resource)
        Glide.with(this@TestBitmapActivity)
            .asBitmap()
            .load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mymodeapp-3f9a7.appspot.com/o/heroes%2Fman%2Fhero_man.png?alt=media&token=6358e564-1fe0-41ff-bc87-0e28d3fe1c1e")
            .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                    val bitmap1:Bitmap = resource
                    Glide.with(this@TestBitmapActivity)
                        .asBitmap()
                        .load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mymodeapp-3f9a7.appspot.com/o/heroes%2Fman%2Fhero_sword.png?alt=media&token=f3d003f8-b65f-4e69-afe3-ea9653c3a925")
                        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
                            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                                val bitmap2:Bitmap = resource
                                Glide.with(this@TestBitmapActivity)
                                    .asBitmap()
                                    .load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mymodeapp-3f9a7.appspot.com/o/heroes%2Fman%2Fhero_wear.png?alt=media&token=4f88b869-347e-4bf8-842e-4a728b8d743f")
                                    .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
                                        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                                            val bitmap3:Bitmap = resource
                                            val bitmapa = overlay(bitmap1,bitmap2,bitmap3)
                                            setAva(bitmapa!!)
                                        }
                                        override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

                                        }
                                    })
                            }
                            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

                            }
                        })



                }
                override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

                }
            })}

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

            }
        })
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d("Test","Erorr?")
    }
```

and the whole problem is that these threads are nested in each other and it would be better if I used For, how to do it in Kotlin?

Comment: Do any of the downloads depend on the previous downloads completing first?

Comment: no, I certainly need to follow the order of downloads, but in general it does not matter

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you first write the code that downloads one bitmap. Then you can copy/paste the exact same code to download a different bitmap instead. Assuming that the result of downloading each bitmap is independent, you don't need to nest anything. Also, the changes you make after copy/pasting the first bitmap should give you an idea of how to turn this into a function that takes a few parameters to specify which bitmap to download.

Comment: in this case, the asynchrony is lost and the program crashes

Comment: @ripusrupus We will need more information to help you. You will need to show the newest version of your code as well as the stack trace from the crash. It sounds like the order that these download is important. Or at least you need to ensure that all images are downloaded before doing the animation or whatever.